# Python3, can't set socks proxy with chromedriver (socks.py type integer error)

Tags: python, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use a socks5 proxy via localhost with chromedriver and python3.5. However, I get the following error:

```
loading
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 97, in start
    if self.is_connectable():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 113, in is_connectable
    return utils.is_connectable(self.port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 106, in is_connectable
    socket_ = socket.create_connection((host, port), 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/socks.py", line 766, in connect
    _BaseSocket.connect(self, proxy_addr)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Here's the code I'm using.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9000")

print("loading")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
print("getting url")
browser.get("http://www.atagar.com/echo.php")
```

Is this a bug in webdriver.py and how it parses the options and sends them to bind to the proxy?  Or is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I've now confirmed the same issue when trying to use Firefox and geckdriver instead of chromedriver.  Starting to feel like a bug in webdriver or a version issue.  Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar problem. This is how i got it working eventually.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxyType = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy.autodetect = False
proxy.httpProxy = proxy.sslProxy = proxy.socksProxy = "127.0.0.1:9000"
options.Proxy = proxy
options.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/benjamin/Developer/chromedriver', 
                          chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Upvoted. Also, chrome_options has been deprecated. So you'd want to use options instead.