# Open a Chrome Instance With Selenium Webdriver With Proxy IP

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, proxy

I'd like to open a Chrome instance on Python though selenium using a proxy to hide my real IP and stop getting blocked when I scrape certain websites.

I have been going thought several similar posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662935/python3-cant-set-socks-proxy-with-chromedriver-socks-py-type-integer-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082425/running-selenium-webdriver-with-a-proxy-in-python) but with no success.

I am using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "165.22.62.179:8118" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver, options=chrome_options)
chrome.get(target_website)
```

The instance open correctly but when I run the command `chrome.get(target_website)` I get no answer:

[image]

If I open the instance without proxy it works fine. I am getting the proxies from [this website](https://free-proxy-list.net/). I want to create a function that takes as input a proxy IP and returns a running Chrome instance that uses that IP.

Can you please me help to fix my code? Thanks for your help!