# Unable to set a proxy for Selenium session

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to set a proxy using the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = "1.10.186.114:46863"
prox.socks_proxy = "1.10.186.114:46863"
prox.ssl_proxy = "1.10.186.114:46863"

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

I keep getting an exception thrown at the line `driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)`. The exception mentions `Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: proxy from invalid argument: Specifying 'socksProxy' requires an integer for 'socksVersion'`

The proxy I am trying to use was just a free one found online, does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3, can't set socks proxy with chromedriver (socks.py type integer error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662935/python3-cant-set-socks-proxy-with-chromedriver-socks-py-type-integer-error)

Comment: I used the code there and went on "https://whatismyipaddress.com/" but my IP is still being reported which means the proxy didn't get set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Update solved:

```
PROXY ="INPUT YOUR PROXY HERE, FOLLOWED BY PORT NUMBER" #KEY HERE IS THAT YOU ENSURE TO SPECIFY 'http=' or 'socks4/socks5=' DEPENDING ON YOUR PROXY
print(PROXY)
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
time.sleep(3)
```